# How do I create a custom partial / template?

Tags: theme-development, templates

I have created an sign up form and placed it in my header:

```
<div>
    <h5 class="myapp-sign-up-text">Sign up for updates</h5>
    <form class="myapp-email-form">
        <input type="text" name="email" placeholder="Your email address" class="myapp-subscription-input" />
        <input type="submit" value="Subscribe" class="myapp-subscription-submit" />
    </form>
</div>
```

I would like to use the same code for my footer. Is there a DRY way of putting this into a partial and loading it using a PHP function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The thing you're searching for is [`get_template_part`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_template_part/) function.

So let's say you put your form in file called `part-form-signup.php`. Then you can easily include that partial template anywhere using:

```
get_template_part( 'part-form-signup' );
```